# ERROR [LDAP: error code 65 - attribute 'calFBURL' not allowed]

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to add a new attribute 'calFBURL' on my OpenLDAP using rfc2739 schema and I've converted rfc2739.schema to rfc2739.ldif and then imported successfully.

Now when I'm trying to add the a attribute with Apache Directory Studio or manually I have this error: "#!ERROR [LDAP: error code 65 - attribute 'calFBURL' not allowed]"

```
# cat addCalFBURL.ldif | ldapmodify -D cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com -W -H ldapi://
Enter LDAP Password: 
modifying entry "uid=user1,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com"
ldap_modify: Object class violation (65)
additional info: attribute 'calFBURL' not allowed
```

My addCalFBURL.ldif:

```
dn: uid=user1,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: calFBURL
calFBURL: https://horde.domain.com/horde/kronolith/fb.php?u=user1
```

What I'm missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add an attribute to an existing entry if the attribute is allowed by one of the objectClass of that entry.

You should also add the `calEntry` objectClass to the user.

Comment: How can I make my attribute allowed by my objectClass? and how can I add the calEntry objectClass to the user?

Thank you.